# Get the API response and store the data in to an array

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I am trying to call an API from my Angular Application and get the data back use the data in to my front end. I get the response back but I am not sure how to get a specific field from the JSON and store them in to an array

```
 dataList;
 apiUrl = 'GetDatafromSys?prj=123;

 constructor(service: DataService) {
 service.get<any>(this.apiUrl).subscribe(x => {this.dataList = (JSON.stringify(x)); });
}
```

I get the `dataList` back as JSON like

```
 [
  {
    "Name": "Jack",
    "EmpNo":"123"
  },
  {
   "Name": "Joe",
    "EmpNo":"456"
  }
 ]
```

I am not sure how to get the `Name` from the JSOn and store in a array so I can use it as a data source for a dropdown

```
  <dx-select-box [dataSource]=""
```

Comment: What you get back **is** the array you want. Why do you transform it to a JSON string? Just use `x => this.dataList = x;`.

Comment: DataList is entire data response right, If I have it as JSON I thought I can use them in the fields. I am new to typescripting

Comment: As @JB Nizet wrote you don't need `JSON.stringify`. And if you need an array of only names, you can do it with the `map()` function. `const names = this.dataList.map(item => item.Name)`

Comment: That has nothing to do with TypeScript. It has to do with Angular HttpClient. Have you read the guide (https://angular.io/guide/http)? If you do, you'll realize that it parsed the JSON for you. And even if it didn't, and sent back a JSON string, what you would need to do to get an array would be to **parse** the string. You're callling JSON.stringify(): that transforms an array or an object into a JSON string. And you don't want ta JSON string, you want an array.

Comment: You really should avoid using `any`, too. Define an interface, as explained, once again, in the guide.

Comment: @igor_c I tried to use the map function I get `Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

Comment: @trx that means that you don't have any data in the `dataList` yet. You should do it after `this.dataList = (JSON.stringify(x));` inside the `subscribe` method. Or equivalently if you refactor your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an interface for your employee:

```
export interface Employee{
Name:string;
EmpNo:number;
}
```

Now, you can modify your constructor eliminating your "any" for your interface of employee, and also add this type to your datalist.

```
 dataList: Employee[];
 apiUrl = 'GetDatafromSys?prj=123;

 constructor(service: DataService) {
 service.get<Employee[]>(this.apiUrl).subscribe(x => {this.dataList = x }); // here you assign your results to your datalist array
}
```

And now, you can obtain the property of any element by accesing it's position. Or use a foreach function to obtain names o anything that you need. 
For example:

```
public print(){
this.dataList.forEach(element => {
  console.log(element.Name);
});
```

}

Hope this gives you and idea of how to store your information.

Comment: `dataList` should be of type `Employee[]` in your example